# Reactjs using state in Link Component

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a link that I want to pass the state value into, but I received error saying

```
Unexpected keyword 'this'
```

But I can do that in the rest of the component, but not in the Link. Is there something I'm not doing right with the string literal syntax? How can I do this then. Thanks.

```
<Link
                  css={button}
                  to={{
                    pathname: '/preview',
                    search: `?email=${JSON.stringify({
                      this.state.senderEmail,
                      this.state.senderName,
                      this.state.recipients,
                      this.state.message,
                      this.state.cardName,
                      this.state.cardDescription,
                      this.state.cardPicture,
                      this.state.title
                    } )}`,
                  }}
                >
                  Preview
                </Link>
```

Comment: `{foo, bar, baz}` is invalid syntax. Objects require key-value pairs like `{email: "foo@baz.com", name: "foo"}`. You may also have meant to create an array, which uses `[foo, bar, baz]` syntax. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Just trying to pass the state to the search param, I used the suggestion from Maaz below and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax problem is already mentioned in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58907118/reactjs-using-state-in-link-component/58907194#comment104076934_58907118). If you need to pass the entire state, you can use object spread like so

```
search: `?email=${JSON.stringify({...this.state})}`
```

And you want to filter out some stuff, then use rest + spread like so

```
const { ignore, these, ...urlParams } = this.state;
// ... React component code
search: `?email=${JSON.stringify({...urlParams})}`;
```

In the last example, properties named `ignore` and `these` will *not* be part of `urlParams`.

Comment: Yes, this is worked, I want to pass all the param in the state in the search params. But why can't it work by specifying each on of them?

Comment: Because it's invalid syntax. The comment above explains it clearly: _Objects require key-value pairs_. If you want to specify each, then follow @Nick's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58907166/2950032).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to fix your object syntax. Probably something like this:

```
{
  senderEmail: this.state.senderEmail,
  senderName: this.state.senderName
}
```

etc.